# Custom Order with API Platform 3 and Symfony

Tags: api-platform.com, symfony6

I have an entity "Auction" with API Platform (>3) ressource on symfony (>6),

I created a API platform extension, to customize the order of the Auction Collection (and to do other stuff)

the order need IFELSE (or CASE WHEN) with Doctrine Extension :
to order published Auction (with startAt; date field with ASC Order)
and closed Auction (with startAt with DESC Order )

Here is the code of my ApiPlatform extension :

```
<?php

namespace App\ApiPlatform;

use App\Entity\Auction;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Operation;
use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\Util\QueryNameGeneratorInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\Extension\QueryCollectionExtensionInterface;

final class AuctionExtension implements QueryCollectionExtensionInterface
{
    public function applyToCollection(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, QueryNameGeneratorInterface $queryNameGenerator, string $resourceClass, Operation $operation = null, array $context = []): void
    {
        if ($resourceClass !== Auction::class) {
            return;
        }
        $rootAlias = $queryBuilder->getRootAliases()[0];

        $queryBuilder->addOrderBy("$rootAlias.state", 'DESC');

        $publishedExpr = sprintf("IF (%s.state = 'published', %s.startAt, NULL)", $rootAlias, $rootAlias);
        $closeExpr = sprintf("IF (%s.state = 'close', %s.startAt, NULL)", $rootAlias, $rootAlias);
        
        $queryBuilder->addOrderBy($publishedExpr, 'ASC');
        $queryBuilder->addOrderBy($closeExpr, 'DESC');

    }

}
```

This Extension works great with request like :

```
/api/auctions (jsonld)
```

or with filters (on auctions attributes)

```
/api/auctions?page=1&itemsPerPage=6&startingPrice[lt]=1000000
```

like :
`#[ApiFilter(RangeFilter::class, properties: ['startingPrice'])] #[ApiFilter(DateFilter::class, properties: ['startAt','endAt'])]`

But as soon that a filter involve a subressource like auction.product :

```
/api/auctions?product.localisation.city=London
```

I have this error:
'The alias "IF (o" does not exist in the QueryBuilder.'

Like :

```
#[ApiFilter(
    SearchFilter::class,
    properties: [
        'identifier' => 'partial',
        'product.localisation.city' => 'partial',
        'product.localisation.zipcode' => 'start',
        'product.type.title' => 'exact'
    ]
)]
```

Thanks for the help,

regards,